# Can't close the form because it spans multiple divs

Tags: html, forms

I am having trouble submitting a form and I think it is because I did not close the form.  I have two forms in a modal, which is separated into two divs, modal-body and modal-footer.  Both forms are in the modal body, but the submit button for one of the form is in the footer.  The layout looks something like this:

```
<div class='modal-body'>
    <form>
    </form>

    <form>
</div>

<div class='modal-footer'>
</div>
    </form>
```

How can I close the second form tag properly?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can't. you have to find another solution. e.g. close the form in the modal-body, but put the buttons in the footer (i assume thats the reason?) and use javascript to submit the form.

Comment: you have to use javascript to submit the form that way.